# 2 Transistor XOR Cell Floating Output Problem

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, fpga, integrated-circuit

I designed the following 2T XOR cell for my full adder purpose:

[image]

Theoretically it gives correct output for all input combinations. But on Tanner Eda using 180nm technology 5V supply, it gives logic 1 for input combination a = 1, b = 1 but theoretically it is incorrect. Because PMOS OFF for input logic 1 so output must be zero.

[image]

How can I make my 2T XOR cell fully functional for all input combinations?

Answer (score 5):

you have not connected the body/bulk connection properly in your schematic.  PMOS to VSS. But that circuit leaves the output node floating for the A=B=1 condition.  Scan through the various solutions [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53165/11861), there is a robust TG version of XOR and XNOR, it uses 4 transistors though.

If you look at all the possible states, you have 2 transistors each in 2 states for 4 possible combinations.  There will always be one combination in which both transistors are off and thus the output node will float.

Comment: thanks placeholder for sending link of logic wiki which quite informative:)But Why output node of XOR logic is float however 0 is pass through both transistor. Can you please more elaborate this concept.

Comment: First it is NOT an XOR as you've shown with your simulation.  When A = B = 1 both transistors are off and teh output is not driven (i.e. it is floating)