# How to construct CMOS equivalent of an XNOR gate using AND, OR, NOT gates?

Tags: cmos

I am new to digital logic and I am confused hot to construct CMOS equivalent for XNOR gate using AND, OR, and NOT gates.

I found XNOR circuit implemented with gates.

And what I did is I plugged CMOS circuits for inverter, AND and OR.

I doubt it is right thing to do.. but I have no idea how to do it other way. 
Need you help!

Comment: look at this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53142/how-are-logic-gates-created-electronically/53165#53165

Answer (score 1):

You're correct; that is not the right thing to do. The key is to take advantage of the ability to implement AND and OR via wiring. For example, here's a pull-down network that ORs together the results of two AND operations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2G3PG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the OR doesn't require any extra transistors at all. ANDing together two ORs is similar. Using this method, you can implement ~(A~B + ~AB) using twelve transistors, including the inverters. There are more efficient ways that use transmission gates or dynamic logic, but I don't think you can go below twelve in traditional CMOS logic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that circuit doesn't work properly. Won't it leave the output floating when it's supposed to be high?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said it's just the pull-down network. The pull-up network is complementary and can easily be derived from the PDN. I was trying to avoid giving too much information for what might be a homework problem.

Comment: I cannot understand it. I never did digital logic before.. :( Can you give more details? This is type of problem I cannot even find right datasource to look for...totally confused

Comment: What's your motivation for asking the question? Do you understand the basics of how CMOS inverters and NAND/NOR gates work?

Comment: If one doesn't mind loading the inputs, an NMOS xnor gate only requires two transistors and one passive pullup.  Even adding inverters to buffer both inputs only increases the tally to four transistors and three pullups.  I don't know if any practical NMOS devices used such a design; it's interesting that it really doesn't translate to CMOS very well.